# Flat list of work items with restriction on parent's Iteration path

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want a query that shows me the open bugs for this iteration.
Our iteration is set on the product backlog items.

Currently I have a "Tree of work items" query.
I match on top-level work items first to have the correct iteration path.
Then I filter the children on type bug etc.

This gives me the correct child items, but all PBI items are included as well.
Especially the count of items is wrong now.

What I want is a list (preferably flat) with just the bugs.

Can I do something like Parent.IterationPath = "myIterationPath"?

Comment: I would consider switching to the Scrum template (the only one that can actually call itself agile) as bugs will then be on the backlog where they should be.

Comment: If you are on the scrum template then bugs are on the backlog and end up in an iteration. Then it is just a flat query.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that the iteration path of the bugs should be the same as their parent? I'm new to the team here and I'll have to ask what the origin of these paths is.

Comment: Yes - bugs in an interaction should have the path of the iteration. This is out of the box behaviour in VS and MTM.

Comment: It appears the bugs have the path they were found in, but this can be different then the sprint they are solved in. If they should always be the same as their parent, then why do they have their own value?

Comment: They should not have parents. They are pieces of work in their own right that need to be prioritised with PBI's and delivered in their own right. They may be the result of a failing test case that is related to a pbi.

Comment: You can have a report that shows the iteration that the bugs were found in, but I don't see the value...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your bugs that exist in the iteration should have the correct iteration path. This is out of the box behaviour for bugs created by the team within the tools.

You use the term PBI so I can only assume that you are on the Scrum template. In the scrum template bugs exist at the same level as a PBI and are on the backlog. While they might be related to a PBI this is not a parent/child relationship.

If you have a small bugs that does not need priorities on the backlog you should consider creating a Task instead.

Comment: This is probably the correct solution, although this will require some effort to switch processes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flip the query on its head.

Using the "Work item with direct links" query type add bugs to the top, and on the bottom add PBI with the current iteration.

Comment: this gives me every bug with it's parent underneath, practically doubling the total number of items